# Why is my website loading so slow? How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, optimization, web

My website at http://droid.ly is loading extremely slowly!
What can I do to fix it? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems quite alright from my site, loaded it in less than 400ms. You may want to consult [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules?hl=en). Implement the best practices, it will surely improve. Add a page speed extension in your chrome to check.

Comment: http://droid.ly/fonts/fontawesome-webfont862f.woff took 4 seconds !

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdroid.ly%2F

Answer (score 6):

> Here are couple of things you can try to reduce loading time.

1. First of all if you are using JS and you are giving online path then try to use that file in your code and give path from you project.instead of using online paths for JS.
2. Remove Comments and white spaces from javascript. you can use online javascript Compression tool to remove white spaces and comments.
3. Enable browser caching
4. Avoid bad requests. check whether you have any broken link.if you do have then make it correct or remove
5. Try to Use Internal / external CSS .. and dont use inline styles.
6. Reduce the number of plugins you use on your site
7. Put CSS at the top and JS at the bottom
8. Last but not Least .. Image plays roles in site loading time. try to use optimize image..

> For more Please follow the link below..
>   [Reducing site loading time](http://blog.crazyegg.com/2013/12/11/speed-up-your-website/)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a landing page (one page site) and You have TOO MUCH images on it.
The browser needs to pre-load all the images and that takes some time.

1 - Optimize the images for web view
2 - Try to reduce the amount of your images
3 - Use a plugin that loads the images while scrolling, so the request will be reduced

Try this plugin:
 'http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/index.htm'

Or this one:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

In this way you will reduce the page load problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have some high resolution PNG images that will load quite slow depending on the connection. Using JPEG format for high resolution photos instead of PNG can reduce their size quite a bit, without significant quality loss. Apart from that consider concatenating and minifying your scripts/stylesheets and gzip everything if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Open chrome, then open developer tools, open Audits tab, chose "Reload page and Audit...", push run button.
Chrome will give you the same advices, as in this answers.

### From me:

1. Make one css file from all css you have.
2. Make one js file from all js you have.
3. Resize images on server, make them smaller.
4. Are you sure, that you are using all symbols from your font files ?Try to remove unused symbols from font files (you can create custom font file from svg files, i manage my fonts via https://icomoon.io/)

**And you will see the difference**